# javascript setting a var with a new line break in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site with a commenting system.  The system grabs the previous comment, and adds it to the next one.

```
In reply to your comment:\n<?php echo $_POST['firstComment'];?>\n-------------\n
```

When the user tries to add a new comment I would grab the above line and throw it here:

```
$('#addCommentButton').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('name');
            var firstComment = "<?php echo $bodyComment;?>";
            $.ajax({.......
```

The problem is  the var firstComment gets defined as:

```
"In reply to your comment:
 g
  -------------
  asdfasfasfsfsdfsdf";
```

and i end up with a javascript error:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

The problem is with the new line break which i need, so that the comment box looks presentable.

How can i set the variable firstComment to what is here including new line breaks?  I have tried:

```
var firstComment = "<?php echo $bodyComment;?>".replace("\n|\r\n|&#13;&#10;","");
```

and still get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `json_encode`:

```
var firstComment = <?php echo json_encode($bodyComment);?>;
```

Just like you would escape with `htmlspecialchars` to output HTML-safe strings you need a similar escape function for JavaScript strings/data;